# How do you convert a character to a key value in XNA

Tags: keyboard, xna

I'm trying to convert a character that I have specified in my application configuration file to a XNA keyboard key. How would I parse my character value to a key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While harryovers has given you an exact answer to your question, perhaps a better solution for configuration files is to convert from a **string** instead of from a character. That way your configuration file may specify any key by name, not just alpha-numeric ones.

You could use `Enum.Parse` to convert the string to an enumeration ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx), [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2004/04/02/106310.aspx)).

Comment: I ended up using Enum.Parse. It dawned on me shortly after I posted this question.`public Keys InKey { get { return (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), _inKey.ToString()); } }`

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
        char c = 'a';

        Keys cAsKey = (Keys)((int)(char.ToUpper(c)));

        bool compareKeys = (cAsKey == Keys.A); //true
```

Comment: This will cause problems if, for example, the character is a symbol.

Comment: This is a good solution, however I didn't want to hard-code anything. I am currently reading in the key values from my app.config file, so I can't compare the character to a key value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Windows, take a look at the KeysConverter class in System.Windows.Forms. Technically XNA Keys != Windows Forms Keys, but internally they use the same integer values.